# How can I see the coordinate/transformation change when I change the pose of a model?

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, transforms, coordinates

For example, if I rotate the right forearm of my model in blender, how can I see that the model's forearm changed numerically?

Comment: Press N and go to the item menu

Comment: thank you so much this is what i was looking for!